# In jQuery, what does "find('> span')" do?

Tags: jquery, find

I don't understand what `find('> span')` does.

Could you please explain it?

**HTML Code**

```
<button>Ibis<span class="bg"><span>Ibis</span></span></button>
```

**jQuery Code**

```
$(this).find('> span').animate( { width: '100%' } );
```

Comment: You can rewrite this using `.children('span')` which might make it easier to read in the future. [Docs](https://api.jquery.com/children/)

Comment: @Jack Thank you. I got what you meant.

Answer (score 2):

`$(this).find('> span')`

finds a span that is an immediate child of `this`

In your example, it finds the `<span class="bg">`, but not the `<span>` within that `<span class="bg">`

Jquery selectors work much like CSS selectors. It is like writing `button > span` in CSS. That gives you the immediate child span only. Without the `>`, it would be like writing `button span` in CSS, which would effect all spans within the `<button>`

HTH :) and welcome to StackOverflow

Comment: Thank you! Wonderful explanation.